# Create Dropdown list with all Azure Team Projects in collection

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, azure, azure-devops

Trying to use jQuery to get back a list of all my team projects in a collection and populate a dropdown box. I seem to be missing something, my URL returns this:

```
"count": 78,
"value": [
    {
        "id": "0bf6cce2-cac1-412e-8617-43d808249a28",
        "name": "project1",
        "description": "one",
        "url": "https://devops.xxx.com/tfs/xxx/_apis/projects/0bf6cce2-cac1-412e-8617-43d808249a28",
        "state": "wellFormed",
        "revision": 1064067,
        "visibility": "private",
        "lastUpdateTime": "2021-03-31T14:28:43.827Z"
    },
    {
        "id": "cc504f31-3568-4b62-9750-7e4d43574ce6",
        "name": "project2",
        "description": "2nd project",
        "url": "https://devops.xxx.com/tfs/xxx/_apis/projects/cc504f31-3568-4b62-9750-7e4d43574ce6",
        "state": "wellFormed",
        "revision": 1063717,
        "visibility": "private",
        "lastUpdateTime": "2015-09-11T03:48:24.99Z"
    }
```

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <select id="team-projects" name="projects">
    </select>
</body>

<script>
let dropdown = $('#team-projects');

dropdown.empty();

dropdown.append('<option selected="true" disabled>Choose Team Project</option>');
dropdown.prop('selectedIndex', 0);

const url = 'https://devops.xxx.com/tfs/xxx/_apis/projects?api-version=5.0';

// Populate dropdown with list of team projects
$.getJSON(url, function (value) {
  $.each(value, function (key, value) {
    dropdown.append($('<option></option>').attr('value', value.name).text(value.id));
  })
});
</script>
</html>
```

I've been working on this all day banging my head against the wall, what have I messed up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because you're looping through the base object, not the `value` array. As such there is no `name` or `id` property.

To fix this, and improve code quality and performance, you can use `map()` to build an array of `option` HTML strings which you append to the dropdown in a single DOM operation. Try this:

```js
let $dropdown = $('#team-projects').empty();
$dropdown.append('<option selected="true" disabled value="">Choose Team Project</option>').val('');

// In the AJAX callback:
let response = {count:78,value:[{id:"0bf6cce2-cac1-412e-8617-43d808249a28",name:"project1",description:"one",url:"https://devops.xxx.com/tfs/xxx/_apis/projects/0bf6cce2-cac1-412e-8617-43d808249a28",state:"wellFormed",revision:1064067,visibility:"private",lastUpdateTime:"2021-03-31T14:28:43.827Z"},{id:"cc504f31-3568-4b62-9750-7e4d43574ce6",name:"project2",description:"2nd project",url:"https://devops.xxx.com/tfs/xxx/_apis/projects/cc504f31-3568-4b62-9750-7e4d43574ce6",state:"wellFormed",revision:1063717,visibility:"private",lastUpdateTime:"2015-09-11T03:48:24.99Z"}]};

let options = response.value.map(o => `<option value="${o.id}">${o.name}</option>`);
$dropdown.append(options);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="team-projects" name="projects"></select>
```

Note that I swapped the properties around so `id` is the `value` and `name` is the text within the `option` as that seemed to make more sense, unless your users recognise GUIDs more easily than meaningful names :)

Comment: Now I get a dropdown with just project1, project2 in it, there should be a list of 78 or so projects, is the "let response" wrong?

Comment: That's using the example data in your question. As the comment in the answer says, you need to put the last lines of the example above *within* the AJAX callback.

Comment: Sorry and thank you for the help, I'm having a hard time following, it's been a while since I have been using javascript.  I just can't seem to figure out what "let response =" should be.

Comment: No worries, I put the full thing in to a snippet for you: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/p9jw3ka2/. Copy/paste that and it should work :)